# Issue Running MatlabControl

Tags: java, matlab

I have successfully compiled the "Hello World" example found on this link: http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/wiki/Walkthrough.

However, when I try to run it, I get the following exception:
**Exception in thread "main" matlabcontrol.MatlabConnectionException: 
Could not launch MATLAB. Command: [matlab, -desktop, -r, javaaddpath '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/java/jar/matlabcontrol-4.0.0.jar'; matlabcontrol.MatlabClassLoaderHelper.configureClassLoading(); javarmpath '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/java/jar/matlabcontrol-4.0.0.jar'; matlabcontrol.MatlabConnector.connectFromMatlab('PROXY_RECEIVER_6eb278d0-1401-4b9c-b9e4-80512708f9b7', 2100);].**

I have Matlab2011a installed in Ubuntu 11.10.

Could anyone point out where the problem could possibly be?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you check the compatibility between OS and MATLAB version?

   https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/wiki/Compatibility
2. I suggest that you should update matlabcontrol-4.0.0.jar to latest version matlabcontrol-4.1.0.jar which can be downloaded from website.
3. Remember to open MATLAB before running the code and check if you have included all related jar files (jmi.jar...etc)to the java build path.

Answer (score 0):

That exception that you posted suggests that you need to add Matlab to your system path.  Check online guides on how to do that on Ubuntu.